# The file in the container is missing while deploying as a kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have copied a file "sample.txt" into the container using the ADD command in Dockerfile.

While running as a container, the 'sample.txt' file is present inside the container.

But while running as a kubernetes pod the copied 'sample.txt' file is missing.

Please help me to understand why this is happening.

Comment: If it's not there - it was not there, or was removed by something, or you're looking the wrong place, or you've deployed the wrong image version, or the wrong image, or who knows what else.

Comment: can you share your docker file

Comment: The file is present while running as a container but is missing while running as a k8s pod

Comment: How do you check whether it is present or not ? Do you use the full path to the file to check if it is there in both scenarios ? If not, run `readlink -f filename` on your file when you run your image as a Docker container. What is the path ? Use it in a command when running it on Kubernetes e.g. try to list it: `ls <absolute path to the file)`. What is the result ?

Answer (score 0):

can you run below command and check if the file is present

```
docker run -it <image-name> /bin/sh
```

Comment: Running as a container the file is present but running as a k8s pod the file is missing

Comment: then something wrong with kubernetes configuration. check command and argument in the YAML. share the yaml content to find out the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  I was mounting an emptydir volume on top the files I had copied.  Check your yaml file and see if this is the case.